# Get incremental changes to events in a calendar view

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph, how can I get incremental changes to events in a calendar view from a non-default calendar ([in the docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20181123125253/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/Concepts/delta_query_events) there are only examples with default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify [`calendarView`](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004013245/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview) you want using `/calendars/{id}/calendarView`.

So instead of using the default calendar:

```
/me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime...
```

You address the specific calendar you want:

```
/me/calendars/{id}/calendarView/delta?startDateTime...
```

Comment: You save my life ( and my job )